# Swiping horizontally on UIScrollView snaps back to original position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a ScrollView which contains many TableViews aligned horizontally. I would like to be able to swap horizontally to go to the previous/next TableView, however the current TableView always snaps back into the original position. The next/previous TableView is visible mid-swipe.

I've seen other SO questions which suggest checking the `contentSize` of the ScrollView but I have had no luck with this. Can anyone advise?

Setting `scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES` or `NO` did not seem to make any difference either.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * self.numTableViews, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
}
```

Comment: I would consider using a UICollection and nesting the tableviews in the UICollectionViewCells. That way you can set the scroll from Vertical to Horizontal using UICollectionViews default values.

Comment: @AppDevGuy Could you please elaborate on this? Is this better than using a UIScrollview to use horizontal scrolling and enabling paging?

Comment: I don’t know enough about your project to explicitly say yes, but I’d imagine so given it’s common practice to nest tableviews in collectionview cells. Search “how to nest tableviews in collectionview cells” that should give you more information. Then search “how to enable paging with a collectionview”